# How do I share code across Chef cookbooks in a chef-repo?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I would like to share a small handful of methods across recipes in a chef repo.  I know that on a cookbook level I can put code in modules in the libraries directory (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595144/dry-within-a-chef-recipe)).  What I'm looking for is something like that but available across all of the cookbooks in my Chef repo.

I can think of a couple solutions:

- Create a gem, install the gem as part of the chef run.  This seems like overkill.
- Put the file in some folder and add that folder to the `$LOAD_PATH` in the recipe file.  I have a feeling that won't work with actual deployment because the chef server doesn't know anything about the repo.
- Put the file in some folder and symlink that into the libraries directory of each cookbook.

The last option seems like the most viable.  Is there a better/more idiomatic way to do what I want?

Comment: When you say "methods" are you referring to pure Ruby code, or is it code that uses Chef's DSL that could be placed in recipes?
If it's pure Ruby, then a gem might be the best way out, and unless you have only a few lines of code, I hardly see it as overkill.
If it's Chef code, create a library cookbook with LWRPs and include it in your top-level application cookbooks.
This second approach might work for pure Ruby libraries, but I haven't tried it to be sure.

Comment: It's mainly pure Ruby code.  Maybe a dozen utility methods.  I'm not super familiar with Chef's dependency management, but I wonder if it would work to create a cookbook that just has the shared code in its libraries folder.

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't seem to work, at least not straight away.
I still think that the gem path might be the best. :)

Comment: Also, depending on your use case, you could create LWRPs or definitions as interfaces to your methods. This way when you include this lib cookbook as a dependency of another, you'll have those resources available for use in recipes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a library defined function from another cookbook but you must teach Chef that your cookbook `depend`s on the providing cookbook.

So, for example, if in cookbook A, you have a `libraries/default.rb` that provides some function `f`, you can access it from cookbook B so long as B's `metadata.rb` file includes the line:

```
depends "A"
```

See the Chef documentation on [metadata](https://docs.chef.io/cookbook_repo.html) and [libraries](http://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) for more details.

Comment: Sounds promising!  I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Haven't given up on this!  Just haven't had time to try it.

Comment: Finally had a chance to implement.  Worked great!

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on this? I assume there will still need to be some soft of Chef::Resource.send(:include, xxx) statement in the recipe for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 distinct options allowing for sharing code in form of either chef resource (1. **LWRP**, 2. **HWRP**) or methods  (3. "**libraries**"). I'd suggest you consider LWRPs first. I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21733093/1661204) very good in explaining differences between mentioned techniques.