# Chef libraries or definitions?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Being relatively new to Chef, I am required to create libraries or definitions from existing recipes.

There recipes use bash resource, ruby block resource (which notifies another ruby block resource with delayed timing), template resource again which notifies a ruby block etc.

**What would be the best approach to this? Library or definition?**

I have read that if I use definition, I won't be able to notify a resource within the definition, does that mean I can notify a resource in a different definition file?

I also read that in libraries you cant use the resources directly. If this is true, how can I use a resource within my library?

Comment: Create LWRP. http://docs.opscode.com/chef/lwrps_custom.html

Comment: Looks like definitions are deprecated starting with 12.5.  There is a big warning box on this page -> https://docs.chef.io/definitions.html

Answer (score 72, accepted):

So, this is "primarily opinion based", but I'll answer it anyway. There are 4 distinct choices here:

1. Definition
2. LWRP
3. HWRP
4. "Library"

A definition is just a wrapper around one or more resources with some parameterization. However, definitions are *not* added to the resource collection. Meaning you can't "notify" or trigger events on a definition. They are solely for wrapping and naming a series of repeatable steps found in a recipe.

An LWRP (Light-weight resource and provider) is a Chef-specific DSL that actually compiles into an HWRP (Heavy-weight resource and provider) at runtime. Both LWRPs and HWRPs are Chef *extensions*. In addition to wrapping a series of repeatable tasks, *WRPs will create a top-level resource in Chef (like `template` or `package`) that's available for use in your recipe and other cookbook's recipes as well.

The difference between and LWRP and HWRP is really the Ruby. HWRPs use full-blown Ruby classes. If you aren't a Ruby developer, they may be a bit intimidating. Nonetheless, you should give it a try before writing and LWRP. LWRPs use a Chef-specific DSL for creating resources. At the end of the day, they compile to (roughly) the same code as the Heavy-weight counterpart. I'll link some references at the end. You have access to Chef resources inside either implementation, as well as the run_context.

Finally, "libraries" (notice the quotes) are often misunderstood and abused. They are Ruby code, evaluated as Ruby, so they can do pretty much anything. HWRPs are actually a form of a library. Sometimes people use libraries as "helpers". They will create a helper module with methods like `best_ip_for` or `aggregate_some_data` and then "mix" (Rubyism) that library into their recipes or resources to DRY things up. Other times, libraries can be use to "hack" Chef itself. The [partial-search](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/partial_search/blob/f91a489dc98f815ec317c36304a4045c8f075c78/libraries/partial_search.rb) cookbook is a good example of this. [Facebook talked about how they limited the number of attributes sent back to the server](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYZ2GzYAw_Q) last year at ChefConf too. Libraries are really an undefined territory because they are the keys to the kingdom.

So, while I haven't actually answered your question (because it's opinion-based), I hope I've given you enough information about the best direction moving forward. Keep in mind that every infrastructure is a special snowflake and there is no **right** answer; there's only a **best** answer. I'd suggest sharing this information with your team and weighing the pros and cons of each approach. You can also try the Chef mailing list, on which people will give you many opinions.

Resources:

- [LWRPs](https://docs.chef.io/lwrp_custom.html)
- [HWRPs](http://tech.yipit.com/2013/05/09/advanced-chef-writing-heavy-weight-resource-providers-hwrp/)
- [Libraries](http://docs.chef.io/libraries.html)

Comment: +1 Excellent description. These concepts are very confusing for new chef users.

Comment: Hi Seth, That explained a lot. I wonder why the chef documentation is not as thorough as this. Being new to chef and ruby, I find LWRP very difficult to understand.  I would have voted your answer up if I had 15 reputation.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Chef terminology has rebranded "LWRPs" as "Custom Resources" and the "Provider" that is the "P" of the "LWRP" has melted into the background and users just run actions now (the `action_class` is the way to access the old `provider` class).

Definitions still exist, are still discouraged, and still have known bugs which will never be fixed.  There is no reason to use them.

Custom Resources are what everyone should use.  More people should move recipe code into custom resources for reusability.  The basic steps are simple:

1. Move the code into a resources file
2. Wrap the code with an action
3. Add a `provides` line for the name of the resource
4. Change the `include_recipe` call in recipes into a call to the custom resource.

That's all that is necessary for simple cases.  Once that is done the resource can now be extended by adding properties, or existing node attributes can be converted into properties (the node attributes can be pushed back into the call to the resource from recipe mode).

For modern resources on Chef-15/16 consider setting `unified_mode true` to remove the compile/converge phase from the custom resource and simplify writing the resource.

For an example of the conversion of a simple recipe to a custom resource see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63515106/506908)