# What are the practical differences between Chef LWRPs and Definitions?

Tags: chef-infra

When writing Chef recipes, it often becomes useful to abstract some common functionality into a reusable resource or library. According to its documentation, Chef seems to provide two very similar ways of doing this: [Lightweight Resource Providers](http://docs.getchef.com/lwrp.html) and [Definitions](http://docs.getchef.com/essentials_cookbook_definitions.html).

What are the practical differences between these methods (i.e. what purpose do LWRPs serve that Definitions do not, and vice-versa), and under what conditions would I want to use one over the other? At first glance, they seem to be almost identical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [chef libraries or definitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725768/chef-libraries-or-definitions)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate per se, but answered by the accepted answer there.